# How to check availability of user at login or signup using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

/* Login File */

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function checkAvailble() {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url : "check_data.php",
                    data : "user_id=" + $("#user_name").val(),
                    type : "POST",
                    success : function(data){
                        var msg = + $("#session_msg").val();
                        if(msg == 1){
                            $("#password").removeAttr("disabled");
                        }
                        else if (msg == 0){
                            $("#password").attr("disabled","disabled");
                        }
                        else{
                        }
                    },
                    error : function(){} 
                })
            }
            /*$("#password").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("#user_name").blur(function(){
                    var username = $("#user_name").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type : "post",
                        url : "check_data.php",
                        data : "user_id = " + username,
                        success : function(msg){

                            if(msg == "Username Is Not Correct"){
                                $("#password").removeAttr("disabled");
                                $("#user_name_msg").css("display","block");
                                $("#user_name_msg").html("Username Is Correct!");
                            }
                            else{
                                $("#password").attr("disabled","disabled");
                                $("#user_name_msg").css("display","block");
                                $("#user_name_msg").html("Username Is Not Correct!");
                            }
                        }
                    })
                });
            })*/
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .login_form{
                width: 500px;
                height: auto;
            }
            .header{
                margin: 30px 50%;
                color : #ccc;
                font-size: 28px;
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }
            body{
                background-color: #fff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <?php echo $_SESSION['error'];
                unset($_SESSION['error']); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <div class="container login_form">
            <div class="header">
                LogIn
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <form role = "form" action="controler.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for = "username">Username</label>
                        <input class="form-control" onBlur="checkAvailble()" id="user_name" placeholder="Username" name="user_name" required="" type="email"></input>
                        <span id="user_status"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for = "username">Password</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="password" disabled="" placeholder="Password" name="pswd" required="" type="password"></input>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn_login">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

/* ajax file */

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    require_once 'dao.php';
    $d = new dao();

    if(!empty($_POST['user_id'])){
        $sel = $d->select("users","email_id='" . $_POST['user_id'] . "'");
        $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel);
        if($result['email_id'] == $_POST['user_id']){
            $_SESSION['msg'] =  1;
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['msg'] =  0;
        }
    }
?>
```

How can i return the session msg and check the username is valid or not?
i want to check it because i m disabled the password filed if the username is not enter or invalid.This is only enabled if data is register to my site.

Answer (score 0):

As for Login file

```
success : function(data, status){
                    if(data == 1){
                        $("#password").removeAttr("disabled");
                    }
                    else if (data == 0){
                        $("#password").attr("disabled","disabled");
                    }
                    else{
                    }
                },
```

As for ajax file, you should just echo the value

```
if($result['email_id'] == $_POST['user_id']){
        echo "1";
    }
    else{
        echo "0";
    }
```

Also, you can find the following for your reference.[Reference](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php)

Comment: it is not working means ajax returns the value but the password filed is not enabled if the value is true.So please help me to solve it.

Comment: If you just want to remove disabled attribute:  `document.getElementById('password').disabled = false`, let me know, if it is ok.

Comment: It is not disable the textbox if i entered the first time correct value and than wrong without refreshing my browser.why it is not working,the ajax request send every time when the blur event fires.it also respond to value 0 and 1 respectively but not effect on textbox. If i entered the correct value than password field is enabled even first time wrong and than after correct.So please help me to solve out this problem.